# Php variable initialise to database queries

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables

For a particular process I am storing a list of mysql queries in Database using php variables for condition data retrieval.

I'm storing:

```
Select count(1) from Users where user='$user1'
```

I have written a script where I first initialize: `$user1="XYZ";`

Then I select the above query from database and try to execute it again using `mysql_query`.

But the value of `$user1` is not getting initialized as required.

Please fidn below the psuedo code:

```
$user1="xyz";
//selecting the query
$select_table="SELECT * FROM `test`";
$result_table=mysql_query($select_table);        
$select_query=mysql_result($result_table,$j,"Select_Query");
$panelinttable_result=mysql_query($select_query);
```

Comment: Sidenote, please also have a look at this question: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work as when you retrieve data, `$user1` will not be a variable but a part of string `"Select count(1) from Users where user='$user1'"`.

Using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) should work :

```
$select_query = mysql_result($result_table,$j,"Select_Query");
$select_query = str_replace('$user1', $user1, $select_query);
$panelinttable_result=mysql_query($select_query);
```

Also, why are you storing those queries in database ?
It would be better to make functions for this.

```
function userExists($user) {
   $query = mysql_query("Select count(1) from Users where user = '".$user."'");
   return mysql_num_rows($query);
}
```